# Menu slider with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a menu slider for a restaurant with two clickable menus, the lunch menu and the dinner menu. I don't want the menus opening in a new window, just a clean click and the wanted menu opens.

Here is the code I have so far, I know it needs a lot of work, I'm new to the javascript/jQuery world.  Pure javascript would be cool but anything jQuery would work too.

If someone can help me and please explain what needs to be fixed so i can understand this more I would greatly appreciate it. Thank You. [On codepen](https://codepen.io/Alfredoeb9/pen/MQRLzG)

```
let lunchContainer = document.querySelectorAll('div.lunchmenu');
        dinnerContainer = document.querySelectorAll('div.dinnermenu');

function reset() {
    for(let i = 0; i < lunchContainer.length; i++) {
        lunchContainer[i].style.display = 'none'; 
        dinnerContainer[i].style.display = 'none'; 
    }
};

$('.lunch').click(function(event) {
    reset();
    $('.lunchmenu').addClass('active');
    lunchContainer.style.display = 'block';
});

$('.dinner').click(function() {
    reset();
    $('.lunchmenu').removeClass('active');
});

$('.dinner').click(function(event) {
    reset();
    $('.dinnermenu').addClass('active');
    // dinnerContainer.style.display = 'block';
});

$('.lunch').click(function() {
    reset();
    $('.dinnermenu').removeClass('active');
    // dinnerContainer.style.display = 'block';
});

<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logoHeader">
            <a href="index.html" >
                <img class="crab" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/vivid_hand_drawn_crab_decoration_pattern_vector_551463.jpg " alt="KingChef Krab logo">
            </a>
            <h1 id="titleHeader">
                King Chef
            </h1>
        </div>
        <nav class="menuHeader">
            <a class="specMenu" href="about.html">about</a></li>
            <a class="specMenu" href="team.html">team</a></li>
            <a class="specMenu" href="menus/dinner.html">menu</a></li>
            <a class="specMenu" href="#">news</a></li>
            <a class="specMenu" href="#">hours</a></li>
            <a class="lastMenu" href="#">reservations</a></li>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <nav id="menuCategory">
        <a class="menuStyles lunch" href="#lunch">lunch</a>
        <a class="menuStyles dinner" href="#dinner">dinner</a>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="lunchmenu">
            <p>hehehfdsafhkalfj</p>
        </div>

        <div class="dinnermenu">
            <p>hdhfsahf</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.lunchmenu {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    &.active {
        display: block;
    }
}

.dinnermenu {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    &.active {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share html and css

Comment: please format the code correctly by referring to https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: just updated it

Answer (score 0):

Notice how much code I removed!  You don't need to set display if you're going to use an 'active' class to do that job and you don't need to define the behavior of a click on your buttons twice.

Also, if each menu has a container, you don't need to iterate over all the items inside of them to set their display to none, setting the parent container to none will suffice.

Hope that helps!

```js
let lunchContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.lunchmenu'), // notice ',' instead of ';'
    dinnerContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.dinnermenu');
        
        
$('.lunch').click(function(event) {
    $('.dinnermenu').removeClass('active');
    $('.lunchmenu').addClass('active');
            
});
        
$('.dinner').click(function() {
    $('.lunchmenu').removeClass('active');
    $('.dinnermenu').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.lunchmenu, .dinnermenu {
  display:none;
}

.active {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="lunch">lunch</button>

<button class="dinner">dinner</button>

<div class="lunchmenu">
    <h5>lunch menu yayyy</h5>
    <p>item lunch 1</p>
    <p>item lunch 2</p>
</div>
<div class="dinnermenu">
    <h5>Dinner menu yayyy</h5>
    <p>itemdinner 1</p>
    <p>item dinner 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome! I'm not sure what you mean by "anchors", but you definitely could replace the buttons with links in your nav.

Comment: & feel free to upvote or accept answers you find useful here on SO ;)